# Loki Configuration for MongoDB storage

Tags: mongodb, grafana, grafana-loki

I was going through the loki documentation. And i came across storage section, where you can set the storage to be any DB/FileSystem/InMemory. Currently, i need to store the logs into MongoDB. How can i do it?

[Loki Configuration](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/examples/)

I don't see any configuration file to store the logs to MongoDB. Is there any reference/configuration file which could help me set these loki chunks and indexes to be stored in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB is not supported currently. Only a certain set of DBs are supported.

[Storage](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/) options in Loki

> The following are supported for the index:
>
> Single Store (boltdb-shipper) - Recommended for 2.0 and newer index
> store which stores boltdb index files in the object store
>
> - Amazon DynamoDB
> - Google Bigtable
> - Apache Cassandra
> - BoltDB (doesn’t work when clustering Loki)
>
> The following are supported for the chunks:
>
> - Amazon DynamoDB
> - Google Bigtable
> - Apache Cassandra
> - Amazon S3
> - Google Cloud Storage
> - Filesystem